# Kendo grid editable false is not working

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

In my Kendo Grid I want to make a field not editable ,my data source is getting by a Ajax call, I did like the following but does not work:

```
$("#turbingrid").kendoGrid({                       
    dataSource: result,
    scrollable: false,
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "DeviceIP",
        fields: {
            DeviceIP: {
                editable:false
            }
        }
    }
    columns: [
        { field: 'DeviceIP', title: 'DeviceIP', width: '100px'},
        { field: 'Producer', title: 'Producer', width: '80px'},
        editable: "popup"
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not work"? Is there an error?

Comment: @Supersnake not an error,the problem is I don't want Device up be editable,but even when I set the "editable:false" its still editable!

Answer (score 1):

You don't declare the `schema` attributes as part of the [`kendoGrid`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid) initialisation. These attributes belong to the [`dataSource`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema).

Declare a kendo dataSource before your kendoGrid initilisation, using the data returned via Ajax, then use this dataSource in your kendoGrid, like the following:

```
var dataSource= new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: result,
    schema: {
      model: {
        id: "DeviceIP",
        fields: {
            DeviceIP: {
                editable:false
            }
        }
      }
    }
});
```

And the kendo grid initialisation code will look like (note you had declared the last part, `columns` and `editable`, incorrectly):

```
$("#turbingrid").kendoGrid({                       
    dataSource: dataSource,
    scrollable: false,    
    columns: [
        { field: 'DeviceIP', title: 'DeviceIP', width: '100px'},
        { field: 'Producer', title: 'Producer', width: '80px'}
    ],
    editable: "popup"
});
```